# nextjs- typescript- Property 'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I've created basic nextjs app using typescript 
link - https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-typescript

I can not add className attribute to any element.I am getting below error.
Property 'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>

I am getting type error for other attributes also like rel on link element.

[image: error for Head > link attribute]

[image: error 2 type check error]

Comment: Provide code example when error appears

Comment: i have attached images.I am getting same error in browser

Answer (score 4):

See the NextJS [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs#basic-example). The Link isn't a DOM-element, so you need to add className directly to the `<a>` tag, but not to the `<Link>`.

The basic example from the docs:

```
// pages/index.js
import Link from 'next/link'

function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>
          <Link href="/about">
            <a>About Us</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import style from './redButton.module.css';

interface Props {
  href: string;
  text?: string;
}

const RedButton: React.FC<Props> = ({ href, text }) => {
  return (
    <Link href={href}>
      <a rel="nofollow" className={style.redButton}>
        {text}
      </a>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default RedButton;
```

In this case you have to add `rel=""`, `className={}` to the `<a>` tag and not the `<Link>` from `'next/link'`